# How to export database by excluding specific table data?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, export

Is it possible, use MySQL dump to export the entire database structure, but exclude certain table's data from export?

I want to export the database that contains around 500 tables, and `n` no of records in each table. I want to skip the table data of the table named `cron_log` which has more than 1.1 million records and is greater than **20GB**.

I want to export the whole database in an SQL file, by excluding only records of the `cron_log` table. I want the structure of this table and not the data.

how can this be done?

Comment: MySQLdump.EXE have `--ignore-table` command line option.

Comment: Can you please suggest how do I use it?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_ignore-table

Comment: People outside India do not use words like "lakh", so please don't use them here.